latex doubt regarding bolding some problem and overbolding
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts, enumitem, fancyhdr, color, comment, environ, latexsym}
\newenvironment{problem}[8][Problem]{\begin{trivlist} \item[\hskip \labelsep{\bfseries#1} \hskip \labelsep{\bfseries#2} \hskip \labelsep{\bfseries#3} \hskip \labelsep{\bfseries#4} \hskip \labelsep{\bfseries#5} \hskip \labelsep{\bfseries#6} \hskip \labelsep{\bfseries#7} \hskip \labelsep{\bfseries#8}]} {\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{sol}
{\emph{Solution:}
}
{
\qed
}

  
\title{XYZ}
\author{xyz}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\vspace{0.5 in}

 \begin{problem}{1.} 
 Calculate x, y, z
 \end{problem}

\begin{sol}
xyz
\end{sol}

\vspace{2 in}


\end{document}

I wrote this in overleaf, but the output it is showing is like this:
Problem 1. C a l c u l ate x,y,z
Solution
but what I want is this:
Problem 1. Calculate x,y,z
Solution
can you please tell me where am I doing wrong?

Why eight arguments?

because I want to write the solution of 8 problems

It still makes no sense to ask for 8 argumetns. You are only giving it 1 agrguemtn and then it starts eating away at the word "Calculate" in order to grab the rest. So what exactly are those remaining 7 arguments suppose to be used for in your definition of problem when you in your example only writes \begin{problem}{1.} and not \begin{problem}{1.}{}{}{}{}{}{}{} as is what you are defining here.

Perhaps you should start over and start by explaining what your end goal is and what kind of usage interface you had in mind.

you are making the first 8 arguments bold and your input is essentially \begin{problem}{1.}{C}{a}{l}{c}{u}{l}{a}te x, y, z  so you get the output I would expect. If you just want 1. to be bold, just have one argument.

For what I understand, maybe have a look at the tcolorbox package and section 17.11 Creation of LATEX Exercises p.368 of the documentation

Off-topic: (a) The amssymb package loads the amsfonts package automatically; hence, there's no need for loading amsfonts separately. (b) Since you're loading the amssymb package, there can be no valid reason for loading latexsym as well.


can you please tell me where am I doing wrong?

Reinventing the proverbial wheel doesn't tend to bring many tangible rewards, does it? Since your document loads the amsthm package anyway, I suggest you make use of its machinery to set up the environments you wish to call problem and sol.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition} % upright font shape for text 
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem} 
\newenvironment{sol}{\begin{proof}[Solution]}{\end{proof}}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem} 
Calculate $x$, $y$, and $z$. 
\end{problem}

\begin{sol}
xyz \dots % QED symbol is output automatically
\end{sol}

\end{document}

